# Setting State From props Values To Make An UPDATE Request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have Project objects:

```js
{
    id: "",
    projectName: "" ,
    projectIdentifier: "" ,
    description:"" ,
    startDate: Date ,
    endDate: Date ,
}
```

I have a component that gets called when a user clicks on an "Update Project" button. The specific `Project` that they clicked on gets passed into the `UpdateProject` component via `props`.

When I try to `console.log(props.project)` right below the `const updateProject = (props) => {` line, I can see the object coming in. Great. :-)

```js
{
    id: 3,
    projectName: "Name" ,
    projectIdentifier: "1234" ,
    description:"Project description" ,
    startDate: "02-11-2022" ,
    endDate: "02-11-2022" ,
}
```

However, I am having trouble setting the state in this component. I need to be able to update the details of the `Project` object and send that UPDATE request to the server.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router";
import { getProject, createProject } from "../../actions/projectActions";

const UpdateProject = (props) => {
  console.log(props.project); //the Project object is coming in!!!
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  const { id } = useParams();

  const [projectName, setProjectName] = useState(props.project.projectName);
  console.log(props.project.projectName); <---- this is defined in console.log :-)
  console.log(projectName); <---- this is "undefined"

  const [projectIdentifier, setProjectIdentifier] = useState(
    props.project.projectIdentifier
  );
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(props.project.description);
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(props.project.startDate);
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(props.project.endDate);
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState(props.project.errors);

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    id,
    projectName: props.project.projectName,
    projectIdentifier: props.project.projectIdentifier,
    description: props.project.description,
    startDate: props.project.startDate,
    endDate: props.project.endDate,
  });


console.log("state before useEffect: ", state); // <--- here, id is the only thing console logging. Every other key is returning 'undefined'

useEffect(() => {
    if (props.errors) {
       setErrors(props.errors);
    }

    props.onGetProject(id, navigate);

    console.log("STATE: ", state); <--- again, id is the only thing console logging. Every other key is returning 'undefined'
  }, [props.errors]);


  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const updateProject = {
      id: this.state.id,
      projectName: this.state.projectName,
      projectIdentifier: this.state.projectIdentifier,
      description: this.state.description,
      startDate: this.state.startDate,
      endDate: this.state.endDate,
      errors: {},
    };

    props.onCreateProject(updateProject, navigate);
  };
```

For the rest of the component, my inputs in the `return()` method look like this, for example:

```js
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
              <div className="form-group">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className={classNames("form-control form-control-lg ", {
                    "is-invalid": errors.projectName,
                  })}
                  placeholder="Project Name"
                  name="projectName"
                  defaultValue={props.project.projectName}
                  onChange={(e) => setProjectName(e.target.value)}
                />
                 {errors.projectName && (
                  <div className="invalid-feedback">{errors.projectName}</div>
                )} 
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's anti-pattern to store passed props into local component state, just consume the prop value directly. You are also incorrectly referencing a `this` in the submit handler. `this` is OFC simply undefined in function components.

From what I can tell you are wanting to initialize the `projectName` from props, update this value in a form, and upon submitting the form, use this `projectName` state along with the project object passed as props to update a project.

Use an `useEffect` hook to keep the local state synchronized with the `project` object if/when the `props.project` updates.

```
const [projectName, setProjectName] = useState(props.project.projectName);

useEffect(() => {
  setProjectName(props.project.projectName);
}, [props.project.projectName]);
```

Merge this `projectName` state with the `props.project` object in the submit handler.

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const updateProject = {
    ...props.project, // <-- shallow copy props.project object
    id,               // <-- id from params
    projectName,      // <-- projectName state
    errors: {},
  };

  props.onCreateProject(updateProject, navigate);
};
```

The form should use a controlled input, using the `projectName` state as the value.

```
<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
  <div className="form-group">
    <input
      type="text"
      className={classNames(
        "form-control form-control-lg ",
        { "is-invalid": errors.projectName }
      )}
      placeholder="Project Name"
      name="projectName"
      value={projectName}
      onChange={(e) => setProjectName(e.target.value)}
    />
    {errors.projectName && (
      <div className="invalid-feedback">{errors.projectName}</div>
    )} 
  </div>
</form>
```

### Update

Since you are attempting to convert a class component to a function component, here are some basic steps:

1. Convert class to function and body, change `render` method to be the function return.
2. Convert component `state` into a `useState` hook.
3. Convert the `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle methods into one or more `useEffect` hooks with appropriate dependency array.
4. Convert all references to `this.state` to the new state variables, and `this.props` to `props` or any variables destructured from `props`.

[Class component being converted](https://github.com/AgileIntelligence/AgileIntPPMTool/blob/branch26/ppmtool-react-client/src/components/Project/UpdateProject.js)

Function component version:

```
const UpdateProject = ({ createProject, getProject, project }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { id } = useParams();

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    id: "",
    projectName: "",
    projectIdentifier: "",
    description: "",
    startDate: "",
    endDate: ""
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setState(project); // update project state when project prop updates
  }, [project]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getProject(id, navigate); // fetch project when id updates
  }, [id]);

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setState((state) => ({
      ...state,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }));
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const updateProject = {
      ...state
    };

    createProject(updateProject, navigate);
  };

  return (
    <div className="project">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-8 m-auto">
            <h5 className="display-4 text-center">Update Project form</h5>
            <hr />
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
              <div className="form-group">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control form-control-lg "
                  placeholder="Project Name"
                  name="projectName"
                  value={state.projectName}
                  onChange={onChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control form-control-lg"
                  placeholder="Unique Project ID"
                  name="projectIdentifier"
                  value={state.projectIdentifier}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  disabled
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <textarea
                  className="form-control form-control-lg"
                  placeholder="Project Description"
                  name="description"
                  onChange={onChange}
                  value={state.description}
                />
              </div>
              <h6>Start Date</h6>
              <div className="form-group">
                <input
                  type="date"
                  className="form-control form-control-lg"
                  name="startDate"
                  value={state.startDate}
                  onChange={onChange}
                />
              </div>
              <h6>Estimated End Date</h6>
              <div className="form-group">
                <input
                  type="date"
                  className="form-control form-control-lg"
                  name="endDate"
                  value={state.endDate}
                  onChange={onChange}
                />
              </div>

              <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit setting-state-from-props-values-to-make-an-update-request]

#### Adding Redux

While you *could* still use the `connect` Higher Order Component from `react-redux` it's more common now to use the `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks.

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const UpdateProject = ({ createProject, getProject, project }) => {

  ...

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const project = useSelector(state => state.project.project);

  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProject(id, navigate)); // fetch project when id updates
  }, [id]);

  ...

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const updateProject = {
      ...state
    };

    dispatch(createProject(updateProject, navigate));
  };

  ...
```

Comment: thanks, but I am still not able to actually submit the value. I am following this React + Spring Boot tutorial, but I am using hooks instead of class components. The file that the tutorial is referencing is here: https://github.com/AgileIntelligence/AgileIntPPMTool/blob/branch26/ppmtool-react-client/src/components/Project/UpdateProject.js. I am unsure how to use componentWillReceiveProps() with hooks.

Comment: and I would like to be able to change any of the input values. I just posted the projectName input field as an example.

Comment: Yes, I am using functional components with hooks instead of class components with a constructor (which is what the tutorial uses).

Comment: @Jon By "hooks" do you mean, function components? I thought editing any of the fields might be a use case. For this you may as well store it all in a single state, like what I think your `state` state is. Think you could stand up a *running* codesandbox that reproduces what you are trying to do that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: yeah, thanks. Here is a codesandbox that has the gist of what I'm trying to do with getting an object from a parent component, displaying the data in a form, and what I have left to do is be able to update those values and submit them to redux. Let me know if anything needs clarification, and thanks for the additional assistance: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-brown-2oohn?file=/src/Child.js:3630-4201

Comment: @Jon I had actually started working on a sandbox of my own after you linked what you were trying to convert. I've added to my answer. Please do check it out.

Comment: thanks! I'm trying this out now, and it works in the codesandbox, but for some reason when I put it in my app, I can't change the values of the input unless I use defaultValue on the input. But, doing this, the onChange() will not fire. Could this be an problem with the value attr. on the input, or...? I've tried with onChange={(e) => onChange(e)} as well, and onChange still will not fire.

Comment: @Jon Difficult to say without seeing what your current implementation is actually doing. Can you update your sandbox with the code you're running locally to see if you're able to reproduce it there? If so I can take a look at the sandbox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241942/discussion-between-jon-and-drew-reese).